# working project in eclipse from svn

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I create a new project in Eclipse from SVN all the files are created not under src directory therefore I cannot build project. What is the correct way to create Eclipse project out of SVN?

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checkout the project using the svn repo browser (window > open perspective > other > SVN repo exploring).  Then I check it out from trunk, see below.  In that folder is the src and eclipse .project file.  At checkout time you can change the name of the project.  If it's a branch I typically append the version, e.g. project_v2 so it's easy to work on multiple branches simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: I was talking about java language. Do I need to check it out as new or existing project?

Answer (score 0):

The project definitions in Eclipse are stores in the `.classpath` and `.project` files.

If I understand you correctly, you are creating the new project using New Projects --> Checkout projects from SVN dialog. This checks out the project files but does not necessarily create the project definitions (they may or may not be included with the SVN dump).

You can create another dummy project of the same type e.g. Java, Android, etc. Then go to the dummy project's folder and copy the `.classpath` and `.project` files to you new checked out project's folder. Then edit the `.project` file and change the `<name>` element to the name of your project. Then refresh the project.

Any other sources or libraries can be configured by right-clicking projects and setting sources, etc in Build Path.